# Numpy Cumsum Condition over Loop Between Two Arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, cumsum

Solved, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44169554/552380)

Need some help to understand this strange behavior in numpy

I have this two arrays.

```
A = np.array([   [5338, 300],   
                 [4970, 400],
                 [5339, 150],  
        ])

B = np.array([
    [349154, 5338, 100], 
    [349155, 5338, 100],
    [349156, 5338, 100], 
    [349157, 5338, 100], 
    [349158, 5338, 100],
    [349159, 5338, 100],           
    [349159, 4970, 50],
    [349160, 4970, 50],
    [349179, 4970, 50],
    [349181, 4970, 50],
    [349192, 4970, 50],
    [349113, 4970, 50],
    [349124, 4970, 50],
    [349135, 4970, 50],
    [349146, 4970, 50],
    [349157, 4970, 50],
    [349178, 4970, 50],
    [449124, 5339, 50],
    [549135, 5339, 50],
    [649146, 5339, 50],
    [749157, 5339, 50],
    [849178, 5339, 50]
])
bpallets = []
#We iterate array A
for a in A:
    #create a mask to get values from array B where B index 1 equal's to a index 0
    mask = B[:,1] == a[0]
    #retrieve the values
    b = B[mask]
    #filter array b by conditioning cumsum to stop when it reaches the value of Array "A" index 2
    reached = b[np.where(b[:,2].cumsum() >= a[1] )]
    bpallets.append(reached)
```

The idea is to stop the cumsum when reached the value in array "A" index column 2, for some reason in the second row of
A, the condition fails. :(

This is my output.

```
#FIRST LOOP, OK :)
5338 300
[[349156   5338    100]
 [349157   5338    100]
 [349158   5338    100]
 [349159   5338    100]]
#SECOND LOOP, FAIL :(
4970 400
[[349135   4970     50]
 [349146   4970     50]
 [349157   4970     50]
 [349178   4970     50]] this is 200, not 400
#LAST LOOP. OK :)
5339 150
[[649146   5339     50]
 [749157   5339     50]
 [849178   5339     50]]
```

Tks in advance!!!

Comment: Shouldn't that be first three rows for the first split, because we need 300?

Comment: Divakar, you right, i change the logic, read below

Comment: Also, shouldn't the second split have three `100s`  on the third col corresponding to the rows 4,5,6 from B and two `50s` from rows 7, 8?

Answer (score 0):

Do not bother guys, found my answer, i change the logic of the filter to get the element's on b by a negative mask.

```
mask_b = b[:,2].cumsum() > a[1] 
reached = b[~mask_b]
```

This changes give me all the "False", cumsum lower than a[1].

Output

```
5338 300 [False False False  True  True  True]
[[349154   5338    100]
 [349155   5338    100]
 [349156   5338    100]]

4970 400 [False False False False False False False False  True  True  True]
[[349159   4970     50]
 [349160   4970     50]
 [349179   4970     50]
 [349181   4970     50]
 [349192   4970     50]
 [349113   4970     50]
 [349124   4970     50]
 [349135   4970     50]]

5339 150 [False False False  True  True]
[[449124   5339     50]
 [549135   5339     50]
 [649146   5339     50]]
```